# Django + calculating with /

Tags: django

how can I get the result of 'score'

```
def look(request, marcador):
    look = get_object_or_404(Look, marcador=marcador)
    num_votos = Voto.objects.filter(look=look)
    valores = num_votos.aggregate(soma=Sum('valor'))
    score = valores / num_votos ??? <- error
```

(Pdb)num_votos
[, , , , , ]

(Pdb)valores
{'soma': 15}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Avg` to calculate an average:

```
score = Voto.objects.filter(look=look).aggregate(score=Avg('valor'))['score']
```

The reason your code doesn't work, is because `num_votos` is a queryset, and not a number. If you'd used `score = valores['soma'] / num_votos.count()` it would've worked.

If you're using Python 2, `valores['soma'] / num_votos.count()` would still be an integer division and return an integer, not a real average. Use `from __future__ import division` to convert it to 'true division', so it returns a float.

Comment: Good point about the `Avg`! Please also note that `valores['soma']` should have also be used instead of just `valores`.